Kafka Streams Error: Invalid topology: Topic has already been registered by another source
I am currently working on a Kafka Streams application where I am trying to set up a GlobalKTable and a KStream using the same topic (sampleTopic). However, I am encountering the following error when attempting to start my application:

Failed to instantiate [org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams]: Factory method 'kafkaStreams' threw exception with message: Invalid topology: Topic sampleTopic has already been registered by another source.

How can I resolve the issue while still using both a GlobalKTable and a KStream for the same topic?
@Bean
public KafkaStreams kafkaStreams(@Qualifier("streamsBuilder") StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericRecord.class.getName());

    Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
    final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

    // GlobalKTable
    GlobalKTable<String, GenericRecord> globalKTable = streamsBuilder.globalTable(sampleTopic,
        Materialized.<String, GenericRecord, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(storeName + "-global")
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(valueGenericAvroSerde)
    );

    // KStream
    KStream<String, GenericRecord> kStream = streamsBuilder.stream(sampleTopic,
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueGenericAvroSerde));

    KStream<String, GenericRecord> joinedStream = kStream.leftJoin(
        globalKTable,
        (key, valueFromStream) -> key,
        (valueFromStream, valueFromTable) -> {
            if (valueFromTable == null) {
                return valueFromStream;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    );

    processJoinedStream(joinedStream);

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), kafkaStreamsConfiguration().asProperties());
    streams.start();

    return streams;
}

private void processJoinedStream(KStream<String, GenericRecord> joinedStream) {
    joinedStream.foreach((key, value) -> {
        List<ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord>> consumerRecords = Collections.singletonList(
            new ConsumerRecord<>(key, 0, 0L, key, value));
        dataProvider.consumeRecords(consumerRecords);
    });
}


Are you re-using @Qualifier("streamsBuilder") somewhere else? Each started builder needs to be unique. Also, ideally, you use Spring-Kafka to construct this, and use Spring Lifecycle to actually start the topology https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/streams.html
